# Are there websites with clinical trial reports freely available for download?

Tags: clinical-study, reference-request, regulatory-agencies

I'm a translator, and I'm currently translating clinical trial reports, Russian to English. I wonder if there are depositories of freely available clinical trial reports, with all appendixes and all data. I want to read some reports to make sure that I'm using the correct terminology.

I have [ICH guideline documents](https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/ich-e3-structure-content-clinical-study-reports), of course, but seeing real-life reports, especially the adverse events tables and other table-form data can be helpful.

Comment: Is this example good enough: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4794896/ ?

Comment: Simply go to [pubmed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/), search for a few keywords and narrow your seach results to "free full text" only. There are plenty of free full text articles, I would says almost every other article is a free full text.

Comment: You could try googling for "clinical trial report open access". Open Access denotes free access publishing, which may be what you are looking for.

Comment: The answer from @naco and jan  seems to be based on a misunderstanding. He is not asking for a clinical paper; it's about examples of documents for submission to regulatory authorities, that follow [ICHE3 guidelines](https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/ich-e3-structure-content-clinical-study-reports) .

Comment: Although the document itself does not follow the ICHE3 guidelines, the [review report](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/24987/how-to-find-fdas-and-emas-review-reports-and-related-minutes) may be useful in considering the tone of the English language, etc.

Comment: Some drug companies appear to have published their own abridged versions of the This is the website of Pfizer's Japan branch (the website is in Japanese, but the report is written in English).https://www.pfizer.co.jp/pfizer/development/clinical_result/

Answer (score 1):

You could try [ClinicalTrials.gov](https://clinicaltrials.gov/), where you can search a massive database of clinical trials in every stage of completion.